# Printing values of the arrays

Tags: python

take the case that

```
x = [1, 2];
y = [3, 4];
z = [5, 6];

tp = (x, y, z)

print_tpl(tuple)
```

actually i want to print values of arrays which are in tp in this way

> 135 136 145 146 235 236 245 246

---

Could you help me to write "print_tpl" function considering that tp may have more than 3 variables in itself. it may be (x, y) or (x, y, z, n, m)

I tried to write it by nested for or recursive function, but i cant handle it
its  really driving me crazy

look forward some help :(

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far. thanks.

Comment: You might look into `itertools.product` for finding all combinations with all other combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools

def print_tpl(tp):
     print (list(itertools.product(*tp)))


x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 4]
z = [5, 6]

tp = (x, y, z)

print_tpl(tp)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for

Comment: You're welcom! Im glad that I helped :) @Roshan